# Importing XML with multiple tables to VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

So I have the following .XML file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PPG>
<Header>
  <Protocol>
     <Message>MixDataInterface</Message>
     <Name>PPG</Name>
     <Version>1.3.0</Version>
  </Protocol>
  <Transaction>
     <TransactionID>2577f125-663d-4351-909c-02fab90f21fd</TransactionID>
     <TransactionDate>2016-10-13T22:48:09</TransactionDate>
  </Transaction>
  <ShopInfo>
     <PPGShopID />
     <ShopID>DB</ShopID>
     <ShopName>TRAXX</ShopName>
  </ShopInfo>
</Header>
<MixDataInterface>
  <ROData>
     <ROCount>5</ROCount>
     <RepairOrders>
        <RO>
           <ROCounter>1</ROCounter>
           <RONumber>UNASSIGNED</RONumber>
           <Notes />
           <Undercoat>False</Undercoat>
           <Clearcoat>False</Clearcoat>
           <Basecoat>True</Basecoat>
           <TotalLiquidCost>0.00</TotalLiquidCost>
           <TotalSundryCost>0.00</TotalSundryCost>
           <MixCount>1</MixCount>
           <Mixes>
              <Mix>
                 <MixCounter>1</MixCounter>
                 <MixRONumber>UNASSIGNED</MixRONumber>
                 <MixedDate>2016-10-05T00:00:00</MixedDate>
                 <MixedBy />
                 <MixedByEmployeeID />
                 <MixCost>0.00</MixCost>
                 <PPGBrandCode>7EFBB</PPGBrandCode>
                 <ColorMixDescription>AQUABASE PLUS (AQU+ BC Solid) 7EFBB Prime (BIANCO BIANCO , BIANCO NEVE)</ColorMixDescription>
                 <FormulaType>Standard</FormulaType>
                 <ComponentCount>4</ComponentCount>
                 <Components>
                    <Component>
                       <ComponentCounter>1</ComponentCounter>
                       <ComponentRONumber>UNASSIGNED</ComponentRONumber>
                       <ComponentCode>P990-8900</ComponentCode>
                       <ComponentDescription>BRILLIANT WHITE</ComponentDescription>
                       <ComponentCost>0.00</ComponentCost>
                       <ComponentWeightApplied>0.00000</ComponentWeightApplied>
                       <ComponentWeightTarget>179.30470</ComponentWeightTarget>
                       <ComponentDensity>1.21300</ComponentDensity>
                    </Component>
                 </Components>
              </Mix>
           </Mixes>
           <SundryCount>0</SundryCount>
        </RO>
      </RepairOrders>
  </ROData>
</MixDataInterface>
</PPG>
```

I wish to import it into VB.NET. I found the following MSDN article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekw4dh3f.aspx but the example .XML file only has one table so when I apply it to my file I get errors.

Can someone help me out with how to import this file into a dataset.

Later on I'm going to need to work out how to update the dataset as the .XML gets updated (I have no choice in this, my only source for the data comes as this .XML) but for now I'll be happy with being able to import the file.

Comment: Importing the xml file will not work.  The xml has too many levels of tags to produce a good dataset.  The dataset will end up containing a lot of tables that aren't very usable.  Can you define the dataset/datatables that you need.  I can parse the file in lots of ways but not sure what you actually need.

Comment: Look into XPath

Answer (score 0):

@jdweng is correct, here is some code to help you explore what was imported:

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sr As New StringReader(sPostXMLData)
    ds.ReadXml(sr)
    For Each t As DataTable In ds.Tables
        Debug.Print(t.TableName)
    Next
```

tables:
Header
Protocol
Transaction
ShopInfo
MixDataInterface
ROData
RepairOrders
RO
Mixes
Mix
Components
Component

Not useful. Look into more XML specific tools for parsing the data.